# Control precision/printing of exponential numbers

Tags: python

What is the best way to control printing of 64-bit floating point numbers in Python?

I can use the `%e` specifier to easily show all numbers in exponential format.  However, I only want to use exponential format if the number has more than x amount of digits in it.  For example, below is the raw 64-bit floating point number and what I would like it to look like as a string:

```
value       what's printed

1.123456    1.123456
123456.1234 12345.6e4
1.0         1.0
.1234567    1.23456e-1
```

Above I only want to see 7 digits total and then convert to exponential notation if there are more needed.

Does this make any sense?  Essentially I would like to be able to use exponential notation only when some threshold for the number is reached.  I know `%e` allows specifiers like `%.3e` but this will always use exponential notation regardless of the number size.

Comment: `123456.1234 12345.6e4` that's not how scientific notation works

Comment: Sorry, your right.  I didn't look over my submission carefully enough.  What I'm really looking for is a way to only use scientific notation if there are more than a certain number of digits in the full number.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably cook up something with `'%g'` -- which will use the shorter of `%f` or `%e`:

```
>>> '%.4g'%(1154.2)
'1154'
>>> '%.4g'%(11545.2)
'1.155e+04'
>>> '%.4g'%(1.15452)
'1.155'
>>> '%.4g'%(0.000005321)
'5.321e-06'
```

In other words, this will print out a number with 4 significant digits and use scientific notation where necessary.

Comment: `%g` only seems to work for large number: `'%.6g' % (.123456789123456789)` prints `'0.123457'`  It doesn't trigger scientific notation.

Comment: @durden2.0 -- I'm not sure what you mean by only working for small numbers -- See my edit.

Comment: @durden2.0: or you could just change your spec. It does seem like you have rather odd requirements.

Comment: @SilentGhost I wish I could change the spec, but not my choice.  It's definitely an odd requirement.

Comment: `%g` is hard coded to switch to exponential format when the exponent is less than -4 (e.g. 0.00001) or greater than or equal to the precision.

Comment: @mgilson Well I don't want to ever actually round the number.  I want to maintain as much precision as the original number had.  Really just want to show it in a 'prettier' format if it's very long.

Comment: @durden2.0 -- This is impossible to do in general if you're trying to keep full precision.  If you want to keep full precision, then you should write as `%f`.  However, this isn't what you said in the question:  `.1234567  -->  1.23456e-1` definitely truncates the original number.

Comment: @mgilson I'll admit my examples were not good.  However, using `%f` does not maintain precision as you suggest, especially in the case where I'm using 64-bit floating point values. `'%f' % (.123456789123456789)` --> '0.123457'

Comment: If it's just output to the user, I don't see why you'd want full precision. A double has about 15.95 digits of precision. The repr will give up to 17 digits, but that's just to map to the exact double for a round trip conversion. Calculations with doubles will accumulate errors, so in general I wouldn't trust more than 12 digits.

Comment: @eryksun I want full precision because it's a scientific application that can require lots of precision.  Also, the users are engineers/scientists so their not afraid of the output, just want to 'tidy it up' I suppose.  Also, I'm not doing any calculations for that very reason.  It's for display purposes only at this point.  Also, the values are sometimes exported for calculations in other applications.  I realize the other application might see problems with floating point.  However, I cannot control the other application.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose I could do something like:

```
>>> def pretty_float(val):
...   if len(repr(val)) > 7:
...     return '%e' % val
...   else:
...     return repr(val)
...
```

Comment: Only posted this as an answer because I can't put a longer code snippet in comment.  This solution seems like overkill, and I didn't know if there was a good way to 'hack' the `%e` or `%g` specifiers to do something like this.

Comment: I think this might be the most direct approach to what I need and definitely is obvious (albeit a weird restriction).  Are there downsides to doing something like this?

Comment: repr uses exponential format when the exponent is less than -4 or greater than 15. So you'd have to check first if it already contains an 'e'. Also, the default precision for `%e` is 6. You'd have to use the length of the repr to set the desired precision, with special handling for `'0.x'` strings.

Comment: @eryksun Could you point me to the documentation for where you find that `repr` only supports 15 and `%e` defaults to 6?  That is a page I would like to bookmark and reference later.  Thanks!

Comment: For `%e` and `%f` it's in note 3 below the table of conversions in [5.6.2 String Formatting Operations](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations).

Comment: For `float.__repr__` I can't seem to find any high-level docs. All I can give you is the C API call, [`PyOS_double_to_string`](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/conversion.html#PyOS_double_to_string), which calls [`format_float_short`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/70274d53c1dd/Python/pystrtod.c#l1057) in pystrtod.c. The latter links to the case statement for the 'r' format.